# Page transition slide in css3 or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would make the same transition page of this website http://www.coolappse.com/ in javascript or css3 (see work section). I have no idea how to get to the same result. Do you have an idea or how to guide me ?

Thank you very much for your answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: You point directly to an example page that is doing what you want. Why not look at how the code for that page to figure out how it is doing the transition?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.scrollTo is probably your best bet : http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: I already point to the code, but I do not understand how to transfer values from one page to another with ajax ... Thanks for your help!

Paulgv, this is a good idea but is not the same effect

Comment: You don't need Ajax if you want to reproduce the website you linked to, it's a single static webpage with a scrolling effect. You might want to look into "vertical scrolling websites" to learn more about that type of design. Also, take a look at fullPage.js, a jQuery plugin to "create fullscreen scrolling websites" : http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/